# How to reset an increment variable when it is called from the second time or more

Tags: c#, variables, counter

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private static int lineReadCounter = 0;
    public string DataToSetandGet = String.Empty;

    private void StatusBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string StatusInfoToshow = "?S\r";
        string commForMeter = string.Format(StatusInfoToshow);
        try
        {
            if (statusofMeter.serialPortForApp.IsOpen)
            {
                statusofMeter.serialPortForApp.Write(commForMeter);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            statusofMeter.ShowDataInScreenTxtb.Text = "TimeOUT Exception";
        }
    }

    public void SerialPortInApp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataToSetandGet = serialPortForApp.ReadExisting();
        string pattern = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\-?\*?\.?\/\:\\r]{1,}$";
        Match rgxs = Regex.Match(DataToSetandGet, pattern);

        if (rgxs.Success && DataToSetandGet.Length > 50 &&
        DataToSetandGet.IndexOf("\r") == DataToSetandGet.Length - 1)
        {
            lineReadCounter++;
            this.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate ()
            {
                Textbox1.AppendText(lineReadCounter.ToString() +
                DataToSetandGet.Substring(4).Replace("\n", " ").Replace("\r", "\r\n"));
            });
        }
    }

    private void CountReadings()
    {
        //Count Readings
        string[] lines =
        Regex.Split(textbox1.Text.Trim(), "\r\n");//Trim avoid white spaces
        lineReadCounter = lines.Length;
        label1.Text = "No. Readings: " + lineReadCounter.ToString();

    }
}
```

If I press button `StatusBtn_Click` it send a command and display

lineReadCounter + reading

`lineReadCounter` starts at `1` the first time button is pressed. but the second time and the next more times is pressed `lineReadCounter` start from `2`.

How could I reset `lineReadCounter` to `zero` or `1` every time my button is pressed?

Comment: @user2864740 be nice

Comment: do you want counter to be zero whenever a person click button in same session or different session?

Comment: Please only include the code that's *relavent* to the issue. `label1.Text = ...` isn't affecting your increment variable problem.

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
lineReadCounter = 0;
```

before

```
statusofMeter.serialPortForApp.Write(commForMeter);
```

so your btnClick event will look like this:

```
private void StatusBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string StatusInfoToshow = "?S\r";
        string commForMeter = string.Format(StatusInfoToshow);
        try
        {
            if (statusofMeter.serialPortForApp.IsOpen)
            {
                lineReadCounter = 0;
                statusofMeter.serialPortForApp.Write(commForMeter);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            statusofMeter.ShowDataInScreenTxtb.Text = "TimeOUT Exception";
        }
    }
```

I think you subscirbed to `SerialPort.DataReceived` event, so if you call `Write()`, `SerialPortInApp_DataReceived` method will be called. Do I think right?

Comment: Yes You right Kovi, I fixed thank you it totally works for me.